# Accessing different panes inside the same window on separate sessions

Tags: tmux

I have iTerm2 running with two horizontal splits, `split_A` and `split_B`.

I am attached to the same tmux sessions in `split_A` and in `split_B`.

I have one window running in the tmux session, with 2 panes, `pane_A` and `pane_B`

When I do `next-pane` in one of the splits, the tmux running in the other split does exactly the same and moves to the next pane. So the tmux sessions are synced.

Is there a way to display `pane_A` in one of the tmux sessions and `pane_B` in the other.

Just to make sure: `pane_A` and `pane_B` are running in the same window and same session.

```
|-----------------------------------|
||---------------------------------||
||   iterm2 split, tmux:windowA:1  ||
||---------------------------------||
||   iterm2 split, tmux:windowA:0  ||
||---------------------------------||
|-----------------------------------|
```

Just because `panes` do not have names, so I would like to have the top tmux names `console` and the bottom `files` and their session called `DEV`.

```
DEV > CONSOLE (top split)

DEV > FILES (bottom split)
```

Apologies for the horrible ASCII art.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about the goal of tmux, I believe there is no way to do what your described. In addition, it seems to me that in this case you can go with one iterm window + two tmux panes, simple and easy. Why you split iterm in the first place?

Comment: I split iTerm (horizontally) in-order to have top floor displaying some `build` and `compile` and `test` tasks. And the bottom floor to be to list files etc. So top floor is locked in constantly running tasks, bottom floor is to `ls` and `cat` files etc. So I cannot connect to the same session (window) but display paneA in one and paneB in the other. I can do with one pane, no problem, just was curios to see if I can stay in tmux. I can have iterm2 running on the lower floor and tmux running on the upper floor. Just wanted to check if they can be de-synced. Thanks.